# identifying duplicate entries from a file on unix server

Tags: awk, sed, grep

My file is semicolon separated file with multiple columns.
I want to remove duplicate records from first column only. Also, i want a count of these duplicate entries from column first only.
any suggestion please?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show some sample input and output, at least a mock-up of the general structure?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
awk -F";" '!seen[$1]++{print}END {for (i in seen) if (seen[i]>1) print i,"found :" seen[i] "times"}' file
```

The first part before END will not print duplicates emulating `uniq`. That means tha if an entry is found two or more times only the first entry will be printed.

The code in END will print all entries found more than once.

If you need to print pure unique entries emulating `uniq -u` meaning tha if an entry is found two or more times will not be printed at all then you may use:

```
awk -F";" '{seen[$1]++}END {for (k=1;k<=2;k++) for (i in seen) if (seen[i]==1) {print i;delete seen[i];continue} else {print i,"found :" seen[i] "times"}}' file
```

This will iterate the array two times. The first time true uniq entries will be printed and the second time duplicate entries will be printed.

Alternative:

```
awk -F";" '{seen[$1]++}END {for (i in seen) print "found :" seen[i] "times:",i}' file |sort
```

This will print each entry along with the counting (unique entries will be found once, non unique entries will be found more than once)